# Apollo client for store in React app - best practises?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I feel the hardest part going the Apollo/GraphQl pathway is deciding patterns rather than learning the syntax.

Having moved all app store from Redux to Apollo cache I am a few days later still struggling with a best way to have components communicate and commonly access the Apollo store.

I could write pages about different implementations but the questions remains as I haven't found any articles or code examples and the forums are dead silent about this - how are others doing this?

To add some to the discussion I have only one React state in top-level (parent) component:
 {dispatch: (...dispatch function...), actionType, actionPayload}

and distribute these through by props and React Context to child components deep down the tree. Parent then monitors dispatched functions and handles most of them (like data manipulations) and passes unhandled actions down the tree. It feels much like Redux but the store is 100% in Apollo.

This has been a thready path and I feel my current pattern will likely change a lot so I'd love to hear from others. Components communicating and app store are the core of every app, surely there must be others out there?!